# Unable to get the JSON completely in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I am trying to get the JSON details from the list of files in the folder. My code is

```
 for file in fileURLs {
            print("check for array \(file)")
            do
            {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: file.path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)

                let userManifest = jsonData as? [String: Any]
               print("get full user details \(userManifest)")

            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

FileUrls contains the list of files to fetch the JSON data.  But I get only half the JSON

```
Optional(["removeDownloadedContents": 0, "globalDownloadedState": 0, "is_Downloaded": 0, "scannedValue": , "globalDownloadingState": 0, "failureCallBack": , "successCallBack": , "is_Downloading": 0, "userProducts": <__NSArrayI 0x7fe00bc2c3c0>(
```

The remaining JSON result is not fetched.  How to get the complete JSON?

Comment: How do you know you're only getting a partial JSON?

Comment: "userProducts":<NSArray ....>(  after this I am not getting remaining values

Comment: What's the content of `fileURLs`?

Comment: fileURLs contain the path of file in which JSON is present.  For eg: file:///Users/usarama/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/38660A06-9205-43FC-A8A3-B261E46F9921/data/Containers/Data/Application/5E1F2122-67D8-4EEB-AE6C-6D4A9C99D46F/Documents/RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1/94af6aa533779db053547ffea5f31a2c